# Where should I ask advice about public music databases querying?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I know there are a lot of [public music databases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_online_music_databases) and I'd like to query one of them(by APIs) to get the most popular/played songs.

The question I want to ask is something like:

> Which are the public music database that expose APIs to get most
>   popular/played/listened songs?

What is the correct Stack Exchange community where I should ask this question?

Comment: May be http://music.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @HackerKarma I'm looking at the 2 minutes tour and it says that I should not ask "Anything not directly related to music practice, performance, composition, technique, theory, or history"

Comment: That was the closest one to matching 'music' oh well... lets see if someone  else posts something

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking for public databases then [Open Data](http://opendata.stackexchange.com) is probably the place to go. They have a [data-request](/questions/tagged/data-request), which would be appropriate, but look at their [Help Center](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/help) before posting.

Comment: Thanks, I checked the "quick tour" and Help about asking and it seems to me the correct place. I'm going to post my question if I won't be kicked out :D I'll choose this as the correct answer

Answer (score 3):

What advice do you want? If you want technical advice about REST API things, then SO is what you want. If you want advice about which API to choose them [Ben's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/264596/262861) is right, SE.OpenData is your best bet.

Comment: I'm looking for a database that supports this kind of API(getting most popular songs). For example I checked the last.fm APIs and they don't expose methods to get most popular songs